# Text formatting

Tags: technical-writing, formatting

[image: example]

Hello everyone! I want to know how to format text to something normal as depicted in the image. How can this be done quickly? Thank you for your time!

Comment: delete the break line?  Not really quite understanding what you are meaning.  You can change the top to the bottom in like 10 seconds of just pressing the delete button at the lines where you did not want it to return new line.

Comment: In other words, I dont want those awkward long white spaces between words and sentences. How can I fix a lot of text like this quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decent text editor will have a function to unwrap lines. For example, you can download Notepad++ and install the TextFX plugin. Then highlight the text and choose TextFX > TextFX Edit > Unwrap text.

Comment: BBEdit does this with the menu command Text > Remove Line Breaks.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. Your advice solves most of my problem. Good enough for me! Thank you!